# Secure boot not enabled and disk partition in install type not shown

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, live-cd

I have an ASUS Q400A notebook which originally came with Windows 8, but I reformatted the hard drive and it is now running Windows 7 as the main OS.

I was able to run both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 7 as dual boot. I uninstalled Ubuntu 12.04 to install Ubuntu 13.04, but now when I reboot the system with a live CD, it says:

> Secure boot not enabled

So I changed secure boot from disabled to enabled from BIOS -- doing that gives another error saying:

> Binary is whitelisted

So, I deleted the Windows 8 volume, extended the C drive to the Windows 8 volume, and formatted the Ubuntu volume (I). I have 2 partitioned drives C and D(for Ubuntu) and 100MB for system recovery.

Beside that, while installing, it won't show my disk partition on install type. It just shows /dev/sda 750 something.

I did chdisk and defrag to see if anything was wrong with the partitioning, but no errors were shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, neither the "Secure Boot not enabled" nor the "binary is whitelisted" messages are errors. Those messages are displayed by the [shim program,](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20303.html) which is one of two programs for working with Secure Boot systems. The "Secure Boot not enabled" message means just that -- the computer is configured to boot without Secure Boot (or it doesn't support Secure Boot at all). The "binary is whitelisted" message means that the follow-on program (typically GRUB) is registered with a valid key. These are not errors and they are not diagnostic of any problems. Unfortunately, the follow-on program will sometimes crash without displaying any output, thus making the normal shim status messages look like errors, but they aren't, and trying to act on these messages as if they were errors can result in wasted time. I do recommend, however, returning to your firmware setup and disabling Secure Boot; it can cause problems in some cases, so it's best to proceed with it disabled until you get things working. If you want to use Secure Boot in the long run, you can re-enable it later.

Beyond that, it's unclear to me precisely what you've done. It sounds as if you've deleted Windows 8 and adjusted your partitions in some way, but it's not clear what happens when you boot the Ubuntu installer. You write that "while installing it won't show my disk partition on install type," which implies that the installer is running but you're having problems with the partitioning. It sounds like you're seeing a completely blank partition table, but I'm not really 100% positive of that. If I'm right, then that indicates either leftover RAID data or a damaged partition table. You may be able to fix a damaged partition table with `gdisk` -- see [its documentation for details.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) To provide more precise advice, I'll need more details. The output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sgdisk -v /dev/sda` would be most helpful. (You'll need to install the `gdisk` package to use the `gdisk` and `sgdisk` commands; or run them from [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com).)

Comment: sorry for the late response, trying to figure out how to post a pic in here .. so that i could get thru the msg.. but i get totally blank partition, i tried with gparted and it gives me error saying /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partitions table as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted possibly by a program that dosen't understand GPT partition table. and now using an msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition table. i downloaded the fixparts, run fixparts.exe, cmd popup.. press enter. nothing happened !

Comment: You've almost certainly got an MBR ("msdos" in libparted's terminology) partition table with leftover GPT data. FixParts can take care of this, but my suspicion is you're using it incorrectly. If you run it from Windows, you must launch an Administrator Command Prompt window and type `fixparts.exe 0:` in the FixParts directory (or after installing `fixparts.exe` to your path). If you omit the `0:` part, FixParts will prompt for the disk device, which you must then enter correctly. (I suspect that's what you're omitting; or perhaps you're not running it as Administrator.)

Comment: i guess i didn't follow through properly, so it messed up my bios and after that couldn't startup my computer.. so had to reformat and back on game on installing again phewwwww.... the part where i messed up was i said yes after clicking enter to the fixparts.exe 0:.. after that windows restart and it keep saying Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0(build 003), copyright(c) 1997-2008 Intel corporation, Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.0.2.3 check cable connection!, -M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM, Root and Select proper Boot device, Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key